# how to check which process/tomcat servers are using certain jdk or jre in linux

Tags: linux, tomcat, java

i want to check which processes are using certain java jdk or jre in linux. there are so many tomcat servers and different jdk 5/6 etc in the server of linux environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check how? If you want to check from the command line:

```
ps ax | grep java
```

will give you a list of what is running and which java they are using. then you can look that version up with the java -version flag

Comment: btw, is there any command that will list down the processes of a specific jdk quickly.

Comment: not specifically, but for a given jdk location, you could use the full path to a specific java to see what was using it, such as: ps ax | grep /usr/local/java/bin/java